# Continue execution after returning response

Tags: python, http, aiohttp

I have following code:

```py
import aiohttp.web

app = aiohttp.web.Application()

# ...start server using TCPSite and AppRunner

app.router.add_get("/restart", restart_handler)
```

Here I start server with the endpoint `GET /restart`. This method should restart server and return `200 OK` to client (suppose, no case is possible of restart failure).

So, how should I implement `restart_handler`? I have the following draft:

```py
import os
import sys

async def restart_handler(request: aiohttp.web.Request):
    """This handler restarts server and return 200 OK in case of success.
    """
    # return aiohttp.web.Response
    os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv)
    sys.exit(0)
    # return aiohttp.web.Response
```

In order to set `200 OK` status, `restart_handler` should terminate with `return aiohttp.web.Response(status=200)`, and here's my problem:

1. If I will put `return` at the beginning of the function, `os.execv` won't execute.
2. `return` at the end of the function won't be executed either due to obvious reason.

Is there some other way to set response status?

Comment: any feedback please?

Comment: Sorry, I can't try your solution right now. But I've planned to implement this feature anyway, so you might expect a feedback soon :)